# Is it possible to launch an application inside a Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, scripts

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 as my main OS, with a Windows 7 installation inside VirtualBox for things I just can't easily do on Ubuntu (like running Microsoft Office). Now I am wondering if there are ways to send commands from your host to your virtual machine to, for example, launch Microsoft Word.

Does someone know if this is even possible? If it is, I could use it to integrate the Virtual Machine more closely in Ubuntu by making some pretty desktop shortcuts to office for example!

Comment: Surely possible. Communication between guest and host os can be done over network. First you need to setup a virtual network. Then create 2 scripts, one send  command other receive and execute command. But it's a bit hard to implement.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, did search AskUbuntu for a possible answer but apparently I didn't search good enough